# Is it possible to scale font-size relative to div (NOT viewport)?

Tags: html, css

I am aware you can vw to scale font-size relative to the viewport. What I would like to do is scale font-size relative to the width of its container.

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the `calc` approach:

```
font-size: calc(1vw + 1vh + 2vmin);
```

I hope that's what you want.

Comment: Thanks but that scales it to the viewport. It needs to be responsive to the width of the container which is not directly related to the size of the viewport.